# The work that they do/does

Tags: grammar, collective-nouns

I wrote this: Read about the work that the researchers and curators do every day.

In retrospect, shouldn't it be does as "work" here is singular?

"Read about the works that the researchers and curators do" doesn't aound natural.

Comment: A verb agrees with its subject, not its object, and it is the researchers and curators who ***do*** the work.

Comment: Aren't 'work' and 'do' in different clauses anyway? Read about the work that I do and she does.

Answer (score 3):

"Work" isn't the subject of "do", it's the object. "Do" agrees with its subject, "researchers and curators". Think of it as "Researchers and curators do work every day. Read about that work."